# Can I do a multiple linear regression analysis with a mixture of raw data and index data?

Tags: multiple-regression, predictive-models, dataset, linear, excel

I'm trying to do a multiple linear regression analysis in Excel using the Analysis Toolpak and I am not good at math, let alone stats. So please excuse my total ignorance. I'm using the following explanatory variables:

- Median income in dollars per county
- Number of people below poverty level per county
- Number of residences owner occupied
- Number of residences renter occupied
- Number of vacant residences
- Median Buyer Housing Affordability Index
- First-Time Buyer Housing Affordability Index

If the index value is 100 or higher, the household is able to obtain a mortgage and purchase the house. If the index value is lower than 100, the household cannot obtain a mortgage or purchase the house (WCRER, n.d.).

The dependent variables are dog shelter intake and outcome data (number of dogs per county being taken in my shelters and number of dogs being euthanized or adopted per county). I'm doing a regression analysis on each separately with all the explanatory variables listed above on each.

Is it ok to have index explanatory variable values with other types of values like dollar amounts and number of people and number of homes, etc., for a multiple linear regression analysis? Would it be better if I did the housing affordability index data separately with each of the dependent variables?

Comment: You mentioned a few absolute statistics: number of people, of residences, of dogs, in a given county. I didn't hear you mention that you're normalizing each by county population, to make them comparable.

Comment: I'm unsure what that means.

Comment: I have all the data in an excel spreadsheet table with the counties listed in the first column and all the numerical values of all the above explanatory variables in the following columns associated to their respective county.  I did not include county population data, although it makes sense that maybe I should've?

Comment: Suppose we're looking for statistical support for the assertion "people here like dogs." And we assess that by examining the total number of dog licenses issued by each county in 2020. Comparing counties on that basis just wouldn't be sensible. You'd have to normalize, you'd have to divide number of dogs by number of people a recent census counted, for meaningful comparisons if you're looking for dog-loving counties. Some of your numbers are on a per-person basis, and others like number of poor people or number of residences aren't, so they're not comparable. You want e.g. the poverty rate.

Comment: That makes sense. What I'm trying to do is determine if socioeconomic factors like median income, poverty, unaffordable housing, etc., correspond to the amount of dogs being taken in by shelters or the amount of dogs being adopted or euthanized by shelters per county. So I'm not sure what the total population of dogs are in each county and not all counties have licensing requirements.  So in that case, I'm unsure if population data would be necessary or not?

Comment: Some counties are small, they have less than a thousand residents. Some counties are large, closer to a million residents. If there's a social effect you're looking for, it probably isn't "number of euthanized dogs per county executive". More likely it is "annual number of euthanized dogs per capita".

Comment: Ok, again, total ignorance here. I don't understand how I would get that information. I only have the number of dogs that were euthanized, adopted out, or taken in by the shelter. I do not have the total population of dogs in each county.

Comment: And I don't believe I can get the data for total population of dogs in each county either since not all counties require licensing.